# 2D graphics rendering in Java

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

I'm developing a game similar to pokemon (Yellow/Red/Blue) and I'm kind of lost on how to create an interactive map.  Any thoughts on this would be helpful, I'm not even sure where to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to learn to use JavaFX to develop your game.

Here is one tutorial, but there are many on the Internet:

http://carlfx.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/javafx-2-gametutorial-part-1/

I think that Swing is too difficult to work with compared to JavaFX, but it would be another option.  For more info to help you decide you can look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318645/javafx-or-swing

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have a GUI screen built in with swing already as a battle screen for the actual matches but I'm definitely going to check of JavaFX for the map

Comment: @Dommol - That information, that you are using Swing, would have been useful to know. The more you can tell us the better response you will get.

Comment: The swing screen is just something that will be used for a small portion of the game, I didn't think about including it in the question.  I was more concerned with creating an interactive map for the character to be able to move around in, but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3):

Try contacting Toni Epple and see if he will release an early version of his JavaFX Game Engine.

- An article on [using the framework as a TileEngine](http://jayskills.com/blog/2013/01/09/writing-a-tile-engine-in-javafx/) for Pokemon like games.
- The engine makes use of the [TMX tile map format](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format) and integrates JavaFX with [Box2D](http://www.jbox2d.org/) for physics.
- Here is [SpaceInvaders in 175 LOC](http://jayskills.com/blog/2013/02/13/space-invaders-in-less-than-175-loc/).

Even if you the engine is not yet available publicly, Toni's TileEngine blog entry should provide with some good background knowledge on how to get started.

Here is a YouTube link to the engine doing [path finding on a TileMap](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=1L1sY2NV8m8&feature=plcp) and Toni has other demos in his YouTube account.

The [Java Gaming forums](http://www.java-gaming.org/) provide excellent resources for Java game development and an active and helpful community.

Comment: Wow, that is a lot more advice than I was actually expecting from this forum.  As always this is a valuable resource.  Thanks for taking the time to compile this list for me, I'm definitely going to be reading theses links in the next few days.